# "Object" vs "Object Document" after XML parsing, not accepted by IE 9

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dom, internet-explorer-9

I am facing an issue after XML parse in IE9. When I alerted the variable where I have parsed the XML, in all the other browser except IE9 I can see the text [Object] but in IE9 it is showing me [Object Document]. For this reason the variable value is not assigned to input parameter.
Code:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
  {
  parser=new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  }
else // Internet Explorer
  {
  xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async=false;
  xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
  }


xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
```

In IE9 I can see the IF block is executing every time, xmlDoc alerted as [Object Document] [in IE9 only], and the code stopped when I assigned the xmlDoc object in input parameter (last line), all other browsers including IE7, IE8 running fine. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
XSLT format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:param name="selectedSKU"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="pageName">skuset</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="selectedSWATCH"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="colFlag">0</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="xslStoreId">10001</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="xslLangId">-1</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="xslCatalogId">10051</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="exitURL"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="iskiosk">0</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="AddToCart"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="Qty"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//product[@id=$selectedSKU]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="label_stars">
        <xsl:value-of select="productcatalog/labels/label[@key='common.stars']" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="label_reviews">
        <xsl:value-of select="productcatalog/labels/label[@key='common.reviews']" />
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XSLT file is preety long...so I have attached one block with it.

Comment: What does your xml look like?

Comment: It's a standard XML format, even if I copied form google or w3school sample code. The issue is not with the parsing, IE9 parse the XML correctly and create the object successfully, but codes are not executed after the input assignment only in IE9.

Comment: According to this msdn blog page, IE9 supports DOMParser http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/15/domparser-and-xmlserializer-in-ie9-beta.aspx. Try getting rid of the IE-specific bit.

Comment: Also, look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476733/domparser-is-undefined-in-ie9. Make sure your page isn't rendering in compatibility/quirks mode.

Comment: That's fine, in IE9 when I change the mode to IE7 or IE8 or Compatible view the page works fine, but in the case of IE9 and IE9 standard, code fails.

Comment: To verify that DOMParser is being seen in IE9 mode, add an alert or console log to the if(window.DOMParser) section. Also, make sure your doctype is set to <!doctype>, anything else might be kicking it into compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, already did with alert. IE9 returning true in window.DOMParser, and also loadXML is not compatible in IE9, I didn't understand the doctype declaration, this XML is executed after some action on the page like dropdown value change, not in the page load. The web page uses HTML5 doctype.

Comment: Ok. So again, please provide a sample of your xml data and/or a jsfiddle with all the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok sure, it is in my office system, I'll try create the JSFIDDLE if possible and share with you. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: XSLT file is attached, please take a took

Answer (score 0):

IE versions before IE 9 don't have its own XML parser but rather can use any version of MSXML to parse XML. MSXML (since version 3) also supports XSLT transformations.

With IE 9 IE now has its own XML parser you can use from script with `DOMParser` to construct XML DOM documents. However IE has no own support to apply XSLT transformations on such documents and MSXML does not work with IE's DOM documents as input to XSLT.

Thus if you want to use XSLT with IE 9 you need to make sure you construct an MSXML DOM document with `new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM')` (respectively `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0')` is recommended these days) and not with `DOMParser`. So basically your feature check `if (window.DOMParser)` is not the right approach if you want to apply XSLT with a browser, rather use e.g.

```
var input;

if (window.XSLTProcessor && window.DOMParser) {
  input = new DOMParser().parseFromString(txt, 'application/xml');
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  input = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0');
}

if (input) {
  xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
  xslProc.input = input;
  ...
}
```